# undefined local variable or method error-attempting to link a comment to a blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a Rails 4 project and I currently have a comment section that is tied to a group section-the group is almost like a blog. I need the group id number to be linked to a new comment. I do not want the user to select the group id but instead have it automatically show up. I currently have this in my comment form, my problem is coming in form the last form-group with the Group Id:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :author %>
    <%= form.text_field :author, autofocus: true, class: "form-control",      
      placeholder: "Author's Name" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :comment %>
    <%= form.text_field :comment, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Write  
     your hearts content" %>
  </div>

  <div class="hide">
    <%= form.number_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
   <%= form.number_field :group_id, value: group.id %>
 </div>
```

What I want to do is have something like the :user_id, value: current_user.id work with each group. The user id line works fine and I have no problems with it. It is only that group line that I receive the following error: undefined local variable or method `group' for #<#:0x007f873a161fc0>

My schema looks like the following:

```
  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "author"
    t.text     "comment"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "group_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "topic"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "state"
  end
```

Finally, my comments controller looks like the following:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def new 
  @comment = Comment.new 
end 

def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  if @comment.save 
   redirect_to @group 
  else 
   render 'new'
  end 
end 

def edit 
end

def update
end 

private 

 def comment_params 
   params.require(:comment).permit(:author, :comment, :user_id, :group_id)
 end 

end
```

Please let me know if any more information is needed. Thank you for the help!

Here are the models for groups and Comments:
Comment:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group 
end
```

Group:

```
 class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collections
  has_many :comments 
  has_many :users, :through => :collections

  validates :topic, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }

  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode
end
```

Comment: Can you show also source for your models files Comment and Group.

Comment: What do you mean by source?

Comment: I mean models/comment.rb

Comment: Posted the models comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without specifying the `:value` option in a `form_for` method, Rails automatically infers the value from the column name, so leaving it out like below should work for your specific use case, otherwise instead of referring to `group`, use `@comment.group_id`:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :author %>
    <%= form.text_field :author, autofocus: true, class: "form-control",      
      placeholder: "Author's Name" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :comment %>
    <%= form.text_field :comment, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Write  
     your hearts content" %>
  </div>

  <div class="hide">
    <%= form.number_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
   <%= form.number_field :group_id %>
 </div>
```

However, I'm not totally sure whether you're approaching a few things right.

Some immediate changes, I'd probably propose would be:

Use nested routes:

```
# routes.rb
resources :groups do
  resources :comments
end
```

In your `CommentsController`, you could now fetch the group_id from the route:

```
def create
  group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  @comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)
  @comment.group = group
  if @comment.save 
   redirect_to group 
  else 
   render 'new'
  end 
end

private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:author, :comment)
  end
```

This way, in your view, you could easily do:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :author %>
    <%= form.text_field :author, autofocus: true, class: "form-control",      
      placeholder: "Author's Name" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :comment %>
    <%= form.text_field :comment, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Write  
     your hearts content" %>
  </div>
```

Note: :user_id and :group_id have been removed from the form fields because those mappings are now done on the controller level.

Read more about [nested routes and nested resources here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

**UPDATE**

For a new comment, the group_id would be nil because it has not been associated to it yet(one of the benefits of nested resources), however if you know beforehand what the `group` might be, you might want to try:

`@comment = group.comments.build`

and instead use the value of this `@comment`.

Comment: Oreoluwa-I think you helped me earlier in the week! I tried the <%= form.number_field :group_id %> and it did not work. The group_id was still nil for the comment. I will try nested routes but I was trying to stay away from them-For some reason they are a little bit more confusing to me but done plenty of projects with them-was hoping I could do this without using them!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. I've updated my answer to explain why the group is `nil`. The question is how does you user know which group a comment should belong to? if you have access to that, you could just set your `@comment = [@group].comments.build`. I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a comment do you know which group it belongs to:?

I think the issue is with this line

```
<%= form.number_field :group_id, value: group.id %>
```

So you are assigning an ID but your group is not initialized. Can you do something like this inside new method

```
def new
  @group = Group.find(...) # load a group here and assign below
  @comment = Comment.new(group: @group)
end
```

You could also refactor so when you create a comment you go to tested route like /groups/ID/comments and then the group ID will be inside params

Hope it helps

Comment: Yeah, the problem is within the line: <%= form.number_field :group_id, value: group.id %> . What should I place in the new method above: should it be @group = Group.find(params[:id]) ?

Comment: Do you know group that comments belongs to...just load the @group for example @ group = Group.find(params[:group_id] or something...so the question is how do you know to which group your comment belongs to?

Comment: When you go to comments route how is the group referenced? Can you also post your router file?

Comment: Yeah-I think that is the problem-my comments do not know to which group they belong to. I think that is the piece of code that I am leaving out. If I do @group = Group.find(params[:id]) then I get an Couldn't find Group with 'id'= error message

Comment: You could use select but not sure if your UI makes sense...so add your comment and select group to post a comment to. But it should be simple you need to know the group if you plan to use value field group.id...You are not able to call class attribute on a class that is not  created

Comment: Yes, on the new page for comments, no group ID is appearing so that is my problem-I need to tie together the comment and group together and that may be my issue.

Comment: Just use then nested resources like suggested in previous answer. In that way your are browsing groups and posting a comment to already selected group.

Comment: Yeah, I am about to go the nested routes method! Best way to understand something better is to actually do it!

Answer (score 0):

if you know which group a comment should belong to then you could do something like this

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @group = Group.find(...)
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    comment = Comment.create(comments_params)
    if comment.save
      redirect_to comments_path
    else
      redirect_to :new
    end
  end

  private

  def comments_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :group_id)
  end
end
```

and inside your form you could have your comment linked to that group

```
<%= f.number_field :group_id, value: @group.id %>
```

Comment: What exactly would go in the @group = Group.find(...) => specifically the find part? I solved my problem with nested routes but was curious about this other method.

Comment: Group.find group_id, to which that particular comment should belong to